# Auctex hook causes an error when set with use-package :hook versus add-hook?

Tags: hooks, use-package

According to the use-package [documentation](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/#hook) these two are the same:

```lisp
(use-package ace-jump-mode
  :hook (prog-mode . ace-jump-mode))

(use-package ace-jump-mode
  :commands ace-jump-mode
  :init
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'ace-jump-mode))
```

I have the following in my configs:

```lisp
(use-package auctex
  :ensure t 
  :after latex
  :init
  [snip]
  (add-hook
   'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
   #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
  :hook
  ;; (TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions . TeX-revert-document-buffer) ; Causes errors?
  [snip]
```

If I take out the `add-hook` way and uncomments the `:hook` way then I get the following errors each time I compile a latex document followed by a subsequent pdf buffer revert:

```
error in process sentinel: image-display-size: Invalid image specification: nil
error in process sentinel: Invalid image specification: nil
```

Note that when I define the hooks using `add-hook`, that does not produce the errors.

Could someone tell what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out what is going on yourself by putting the cursor after the `use-package` stanza and doing `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`.  You will discover that the `:hook` line expands to

```
(add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions-hook #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
```

which is not what you wanted.

Long story short: `:hook` only does what you want if the `car` of the alist names a hook in a rather simple-minded way.  In your case, calling `add-hook` explicitly is the way to go.